# complete a html table with a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to insert row titles to a html table, which is later populated by a php array whose contents is from a MYSQL query.

I've got the code to do everything, except that the row titles are repeating in 4 columns at the beginning of each row and not just displaying $item[1] for the first row, $item[2] for the second row, and so on.

Here is my code:

```
// query the database
$result = mysql_query($query_getproductbrands);

// cols we are interested in (from the SQL query)

$cols = array(
  'productName',
  'brandName',
  'productDescription',
  'productPrice',
);

$titles = array(
  'Product',
  'Brand',
  'Description',
  'Price',
);

// initialize rotated result using cols
$rotated = array();
foreach($cols as $col) {
  $rotated[$col] = array();
}

// fill rotated array
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false) {
  foreach($cols as $col) {
    $rotated[$col][] = $row[$col];
  }
}

// echo html
echo "<table border=1 width=473>";
echo "<tr>";

echo "</tr>";
foreach($rotated as $col => $values) {
 echo "<tr>";

 foreach($titles as $title) {
    echo "<td> " . htmlentities($title) . "</td>";
 }


 foreach($values as $value) {
    echo "<td> " . htmlentities($value) . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

So this is producing a table containing:

Product Brand Description Price product1     product2     product3

Product Brand Description Price brand1       brand2       brand3

Product Brand Description Price description1 description2 description3

Product Brand Description Price price1       price2       price3

And I would like it to produce a table containing:

Product     product1     product2     product3

Brand       brand1       brand2       brand3

Description description1 description2 description3

Price       price1       price2       price3

I've thought about doing a loop for the first 'title' array, and then the loop for the 'values' array, but this doesn't work.

If I echo $col at the first loop instead, I get just the first value (product) repeated, and I could choose $title[0], but I am not sure how to increment this onto each row and then implement the loop for the remaining data query (values).

Please could someone offer some advice to achieve the desired table?

Comment: waaaa, so many people still using mysql_*. It's deprecated. Move to MySQLi here; it's painless.

Comment: Hiroto, what are you saying- if I use $result = mysqli_query($query_getproductbrands); will I get exactly the same thing as using $result = mysql_query($query_getproductbrands); ??

Comment: `$db = mysqli_connect(*vars); $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);` (*vars are your connection details). So yes, but try looking at the OOP interface. It's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Move this outside of the foreach loop:

```
foreach($titles as $title) {
    echo "<td> " . htmlentities($title) . "</td>";
 }
```

Preferably put it between here:

```
echo "<tr>";
<-- Put me here.
echo "</tr>";
```

If I'm understanding correctly that should do the trick.

Comment: i'm not sure that this works. Am I putting the entire foreach loop in between the echo bit you say, further up the code? it seems to put 4 column headers at the top instead.